# Как сделать вывод текста при удачной отправки формы и заблокировать поля?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Попытаюсь изложить максимально понятнее, чем в заголовке)
В общем подключил самый простой обработчик на сайт, но возникли некоторые трудности.
Когда я отправляю данные с формы - она просто исчезает, при том моменте, что данные доходят до адресата.

Как сделать так, что бы код формы не удалялся после отправки, а поля были заблокированы от повторного ввода после первой успешной попытки?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function () {
                var formID = $(this).attr('id');
                // Добавление решётки к имени ID
                var formNm = $('#' + formID);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'mail.php',
                    data: formNm.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Вывод текста результата отправки
                        $(formNm).html(data); 
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                        // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
                        $(formNm).html(error);         
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
});
```

```html
<form id="001">
                            <input type="text" name="name" required title="Введите Ваше имя" placeholder="имя">
                            <input type="text" name="phone" pattern="^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$" required title="Введите номер телефона в формате +7 (999) 999-99-99" placeholder="телефон">
                            <button id="headbutton">Заказать дизайн</button>
</form>
```

```css
    <?php
$form_subject = 'Заявка с сайта';
$admin_email = 'info@mail.ru';
$_POST["fields"]["Телефон"];
$_POST["fields"]["Имя"];
$message = 'Телефон:'.$_POST["fields"]["Телефон"].'<br>Имя: '.$_POST["fields"]["Имя"];
function adopt($text) {
  return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}


$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
$headers .= "From: Отправитель <from@site.ru>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя


mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
echo '{"msg":"ok","code":200}';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

в коде успешного выполнения запроса  замени строку `$(formNm).html(data);`   на `$('input').attr('disabled',true);`

Comment: Можно еще и `button` заблокировать `$('input, button').attr('disabled', true);`